# Text field is not parsed into date in google data studio

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm having a google sheet file, that contains several columns. One of these columns is Date. After loading this sheet into google data studio, I found that this field `Date` is detected as Text. I tried to to cast it manually using GDS but it failed. So I decided to create another field `Date_d` using parse_date function in GDS, but it fails too.

The weird thing, is the original field `Date`, when I read it in GDS, it doesn't look in the same sheet format:

Sheet format column values:

[image]

When I read it in GDS:

[image]

Based on this I tried to use 2 formulas for the new casted fields:

`PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", Date)` and `PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", Date)` but both fail to be read by GDS:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that you should specify the column type as a String in the google sheet.